# Whats wrong with this code? (function and values)

Tags: c, function, return, function-call

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getAge(void);

int main(void)
{
    int age = 0;
    getAge();
    printf("The age is %4d\n",age);
     system("PAUSE");
      return 0;
 }

 //The function gets the age until it is valid, and returns the vaild age
int getAge(void)
{
    const int MAX_AGE = 120;
   const int MIN_AGE = 0;
    int age = 0;
   int invalidAge = 0;
    printf("please enter your age (0-120): ");
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &age);
        invalidAge = ( age > MAX_AGE || age < MIN_AGE );
        if( invalidAge )
        {
            printf("Invalid age! Please enter your age (0-120): ");
        }
    } while ( invalidAge );
    printf("Finally!!!\n");
    return age;
}
```

Hello, this code has a run-time problem. Can anyone tell me what to change?
There is no compile error.

Comment: *What* runtime problem?  What is it not doing correctly?  I see at least two problems, but you need to give us something more to go by than "it doesn't work".

Comment: please refer some good programming books like Dennis Ritchie programming in c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, in your code,

```
 getAge();
```

you forgot to collect the return value of `getAge();` function into `age` variable. Thereby, the returned value of `getAge()` function is always ignored and the output comes as 0.

You need to change your code to

```
  age = getAge();
```

to store the return value of the function to be stored into `age`.

Comment: Which line should change?

Comment: It's not me..I appreciate you helping me

Comment: But why is it giving a compile time error?..You are saying...returned value is not getting stored in the `age`...but why is that a problem??...If the returned value is not stored in age then printing age should print `0`..right?

Comment: Is it compulsory to store the returned value in a variable??

Comment: @MathewsMathai : it should not be a compilation error .did u get compilation error ?

Comment: @MathewsMathai: the OP said that there was no compile error, just a runtime problem.

Comment: So sorry..!!..@Sourav Ghosh

Comment: OK thank you all for helping.. maybe there is more problem to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Please catch return value in "age" variable like below .

```
 int main(void)
    {
        int age = 0;
       age= getAge(); //catch the return value
        printf("The age is %4d\n",age);
         system("PAUSE");
          return 0;
     }
```